# Bibtex and index of authors

Tags: bibtex, indexing

Is  there any way of automatically creating an author index based on
citations via bibtex?

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4082/510)'s an answer that uses `biblatex`.

Comment: @Anja: Does locksteps link solve your problem? If so, we can close this question as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Caramdir: Unfortunatelly not. I use the \usepackage{natbib} where paper are cited with \citep, \CItet etc. I found out the command \citeindextrue  to generate/include index of authors but now I have new problem; I can't separate the Index of Authors and Subject index (generated with maxeidx package and \index command).    Do you have any suggestions? Thanks, Anja

Answer (score 5):

An author index can be generated from BibTeX by using the `authorindex` package, [available on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/authorindex) where there are details of limitations, including some bibliographic styles that require patching to use with `authorindex`. It is included in TeXlive. `texdoc authorindex` will give details of options.

`authorindex` uses a provided perl script to run against .aux files to generate the author index. The index can take several forms, for example a list of authors referenced or a more detailed list of authors and pages where their works are cited (using `\aicite` rather than the more usual `\cite` is one way this can be done).

This trivial example shows the package in use but without any of its formatting options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authorindex}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
Found in \aicite{diller97} and \aicite{goossens99}
\blindtext[6]
Found in \aicite{goossens99}
\blindtext[10]
In \aicite{syropoulos03} but not \cite{patashnik88}
\blindtext[3]
Finally, \aicite{voss10}.
\bibliography{TeX}


\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

This generates a 5-page pdf file and the end of the final page is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I explained to Caramdir above I use the  natbib package  and the \citeindextrue command which write the citations into the .idx indexing file. I'd like to separate the Index of Authors from Subject index. For index entries I use maxeidx package and \index command. Do you have any suggestions (I use MikTeX and TexnicCenter)? Thanks, Anja

Comment: Why do you use `\citeindextrue` if you don't want the index of authors in the subject index? Perhaps you would get a better solution to your problem if you form a new question that better reflects your requirements and constraints.

Comment: I use the  \citeindextrue command because this is included in natbib package and I didn't find any better solution (it works fine with just on index). You are right; probably will be better to ask a new question.

Comment: The \citeindextrue