# Index both authors and subjects with authorindex and makeindex

Tags: natbib, indexing, authorindex

I am trying to make two separate indexes for my PhD dissertation, the author index and the subject index. 
Creating the author index is quit easy, I just use the `\usepackage{makeidx}` and 
`\printindex` command and `LaTeX` creates a beautiful author index for me. What if I want to add the subject index before the author index? 
I have read the responses to the similar question on StackExchange: 
[How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes)
but it is not a viable solution for me, because it requires me to manually index both authors and subjects. Currently, I do not have to index the authors and latex creates the index for me automatically. 
Is there any way to only index the subjects manually ( I mean to use `\index{key}` for every subject of interest) and have the authors index automatically? 
The \authorindex package does not work with \natbib

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With **author index** you mean the bibliography?

Comment: How should LaTeX know that a specific Word is an author? You will need to tag them somehow if you want a real index and not just a bibliography. What you can do (using the linked answer) is to create a command, e.g. `\authorindex{}` that encapsules the `\index{authors}{Author}` line.

Comment: No, with author index I mean a list of authors and the page numbers which they have been cited in. It is completely different from the bibliography.

Comment: The nice thing about \authorindex package is that I do not have to index the authors manually! It creates the author index automatically. please see here for an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24332/bibtex-and-index-of-authors

Comment: @user50822: Well, you did not mention `authorindex` and `\printauthorindex` at all! If that package generates it for you -- it's nice. It obtains the information from the list of cited authors. The other (**subject**) index has to be done manually. How should `TeX` know which subject is important for you? Say `\index{subject}` and it should appear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have been more specific. When I do as you said, the subject index will appear exactly after the author index. I want to have two separate indexes and control the place where they appear in the document.

Comment: @user50822: Perhaps you should edit your original question and explicitly state, that you are using the `authorindex` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `authorindex` and `natbib` packages collide at first glance, but in section 
7.2.3 of the manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/authorindex/authorindex.pdf) a solution is provided by using a local natbib.cfg, which I just copy from the manual, I have **not** developed that material:

Content of **`natbib.cfg`**:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{authorindex}{%
\ifNAT@numbers
\let\org@@citex\NAT@citexnum
\else
\let\org@@citex\NAT@citex
\fi
\def\@citex[#1][#2]#3{%
\typeout{indexing: [#1][#2]{#3}}%
\org@@citex[#1][#2]{#3}%
\@aicitey{#3}}%
\renewcommand\NAT@wrout[5]{%
\if@filesw{%
\let\protect\noexpand\let~\relax
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\aibibcite{#5}{#1}}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#5}{{#1}{#2}{{#3}}{{#4}}}}}%
\fi}}{}}
\endinput
```

Place this file (exactly with this name!) in the folder where your document source is stored.

The next step is to replace all `\aicite` commands with 'traditional' `\cite` (otherwise it does not work. Why???? I have no clue, but I did not look into the package files either)

I added the rather simple command `\listofauthors`, which includes the authorindex, further formatting is not done, however.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{authorindex}

% Use this, if you want hyperlinks back from list of author entry to page
% where the citation was placed
\def\theaipage{\string\hyperpage{\thepage}} 

\newcommand{\listofauthorsname}{List of Authors}%

\newcommand{\listofauthors}{%
\chapter*{\listofauthorsname}%
\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listofauthorsname}%
\noindent%
\printauthorindex%
}%

\makeindex
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

Einstein showed that  \[ E = m \cdot c^2,\]
i.e. the equivalence\index{Equivalence} of mass\index{Mass} and energy\index{Energy}.\par

In their books \cite{GSM97} or \cite{Lam94} show how to typeset those equation ;-)

\blindtext

\printindex

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{biblio}

\listofauthors


\end{document}
```

> Workflow on `foo.tex`
>
> 1. pdflatex foo.tex
> 2. makeindex foo
> 3. bibtex foo
> 4. authorindex foo
> 5. pdflatex foo

[image]

Comment: You can use of of the existing bib files in your tex distribution. They are under `$TEXMF/bibtex/bib/`

Comment: @Herbert: Good to know, I never looked into that.

Comment: @Christian: Thank you very much for the useful help. What if I want to use the \natbib package? When I do so, right after the \begig{document} I use \citeindextrue and the index of authors will appear with \printindex but \printauthorindex does not work! here it says that I have to use perl. http://tex.loria.fr/bibdex/authorindex.pdf what is your idea?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer again to clarify, with \natbib package, \printauthorindex is not producing anything. to get the index of authors, I should use \citeindexture and \printindex together. the problem is that in doing so, the index of authors and subjects get mixed together!

Comment: @user50822: I'll look after later on.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I really appreciate your help in advance

Comment: @user50822: Well, there are incompatibilities with `natbib`, as stated in the manual also obtainable from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/authorindex, but it can be solved (see section 7.2.3 of `authorindex.pdf`) with a special `natbib.cfg` file and replacing `\aicite` with `cite`. Nevertheless, the perl script `authorindex` has to be used.

Comment: @user50822: Does it work now?