# debugging authorindex

Tags: babel, authorindex

I have two books for which I want to create an author index using `authorindex`. Creating the index works for my book but not for the book somebody else has written. This is what I get as an error message:

```
authorindex -p -i test.aux
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
The top-level auxiliary file: _autidx_.aux
The style file: _autidx_.bst
I found no \citation commands---while reading file _autidx_.aux
Database file #1: biblio.bib
(There was 1 error message)
BibTeX error. Aborting leaving all temporary files _autidx_.*
```

I do not know what to do. How can I debug this? What may be the problem?

*Edit*: OK. It is a problem with `babel`. If the loading of `babel`is commented it, `authorindex` complains. Otherwise it works nicely.

```
\documentclass{book}                          


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{authorindex}

%\usepackage[british,italian]{babel}                % hyphenation


\begin{document} 



\citep{test}

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about a MWE? `;-)`

Comment: I answered a similar question some months ago, about the conflict between `natbib` and `authorindex`, please have a look on that question (and answer ;-)) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174379/index-both-authors-and-subjects-with-authorindex-and-makeindex/174389#174389

Comment: Ehm, but I have a natbib.cfg already and it works for another book. The problem is that `babel` seems to do funny things ....

Comment: I did test with the standard `biblio.bib` (being part of TeXLive), and did not get any error with `babel` activated

Comment: It seems to depend on the position where `babel` is loaded. If loaded after `natbib` and `authorindex` I get the error, if loaded before, everything is fine as far as the call of authorindex is concerned. LaTeX complains though ...

Comment: @StefanMueller: I cannot confirm that the order of calling `babel` is important, there is no difference for me. Do you use the latest `TeXLive` -- I updated two days ago and your code runs without complains

Comment: @StefanMüller Please, add a sample bib entry and details about the engine you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `polyglossia` instead of `babel`. And now it works fine with `xelatex`.