# Producing a List of Authors

Tags: makeindex, apacite

This is largely working but there are a few glitches that I'm not sure how to address.  And there's probably a much simpler way of producing the very simple list I need.  MWE follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@journal{LEVY2005,
       author = {Lévy, A.},
       title = {Modification des enchères après une intervention sur l’ouverture de 1 Sans-Atout},
       shorttitle = {Modifications après une intervention sur 1SA},
       language = {Français},
       publisher =  {Le Bridgeur},
       volume={785},
       number={6},
       date = {2005}
}
@journal{RODW2012,
       author = {Rodwell, E.},
       title = {{Eric Rodwell: The Bridge World Interview}},
       publisher =  {The Bridge World},
       page={26},
       date = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[emindex]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacitex}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Cette convention était popularisée par l'équipe Meckwell. \citeauthor{RODW2012}

On suit l'article de Lévy.\citeauthor{LEVY2005}
\newpage
\bibliography{mwe}
\printindex[autx]
\newpage
\printindex


\end{document}
```

The output is :

```
A)
Cette convention était popularisée par l'équipe Meckwell. Rodwell

On suit l'article de Lévy.Lévy

 B)

Références
Lévy, A. (n.d.). Modification ...
Rodwell, E. (n.d.). Eric Rodwell: ...

C)
Index des auteurs
Lévy, A., 1, 2  Rodwell, E., 1, 2
```

A) is fine.  B) I don't want a date and I've partially achieved that with (n.d.) but I don't want (n.d.) to display.  If an author has multiple dates I want them all merged and no date to display.

So two questions 1) Is there an easier way of doing this (I tried authorindex first but didn't get it working)?  2) If not, how to patch B)?

Comment: the "Rodwell" in the title has to be put in braces to retain the cap "R".  ("sentence casing" is applied to titles of articles; that is, only the first letter is kept in uppercase.)

Comment: `biblatex` can automatically index the author names in citations. If you don't want to use `biblatex`, there is a package called `authorindex` (which I don't use): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24332/35864

Comment: authorindex  seems to work OK in the MWE, but as far as I remember there was some incompatibility with my live system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier **not** to use apacite.

I ended up trying several of the packages mentioned at
[List of Indexing Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/list-of-indexing-packages-pros-and-cons)
and spent hours working through a range of issues related to i)interactions with the memoir package ii)interactions with glossaries and acronyms iii)need to have multiple indexes iv)wanting to use a customized citation command "mycite".

Finally, I settled on the imakeidx package and simply following each \mycite entry with a list of authors index entry.  So I've now simple entries like

```
\mycite{RODW2012}\index[author]{Rodwell, Eric}
```

That can be packaged up further into

```
\newcommand{\myciteAut}[1]{\mycite{#1}\index[author]{\citeauthorlastfirst{#1}}}
```

or even

```
\newcommand{\myciteAut}[1]{\mycite{#1}\index[author]{\citeauthorlastfirst{#1}}\index[works]{\citetitle{#1}}}
```

using

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorlastfirst}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```