# biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm using biblatex, and I would like to leave out those entries from the bibliography, where a specific person is an author (it's a PhD thesis and my own publications should come in a separate bibliography).

- It can be done with using a special keyword in those bib entries, and later filter out that keyword, but I would prefer not to modify the bib entries.
- I was able to manage it with creating a category (with `\DeclareBibliographyCategory`), and then manually adding the item in question to them, but an automatic and dynamic solution would be much better.
- `\defbibcheck` seems to be exactly the feature I was looking for, but I'm having problems with the substring checking code.

Author names are a name list, and inside the `\defbibcheck` it can be accessed with `\thename{author}`. It returns a raw form string with hashes, author first and last names, initials. Now only a substring check is needed.

However

```
\defbibcheck{ownpublications}{
  % IfSubStr is from xstring package
  \IfSubStr{\thename{author}}{Author1}{
   \skipentry%
  }
}
```

prints all the references, even those, where Author1 is among the authors.

The substring search and the skipping works, if I use a constant instead of `\thename{author}`, thus I thought maybe it is  an expansion problem. My Tex/Latex knowledge is very limited when it comes to more than the usual formatting commands, but I tried the following (among other random variants with `\fullexpand` and `\expandafter`, etc.):

```
\defbibcheck{ownpublications}{
  \edef\authorstring{\thename{author}}  
  \IfSubStr{\authorstring}{Author1}{
   \skipentry%
  }
}
```

but the result is the same, none of the entries are skipped.

I tried other various checks which include custom macros returning strings, or macros using other fields from the actual bib entry (like year), so maybe the problem is not with expansion but with `\thename`.

UPDATE: a full minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author = {D.E. Knuth},
    title = {The {\TeX}book},
    publisher = {Addison Wesley},
    year = 1986
}

@Book{latexbook,
  author =       "Leslie Lamport",
  title =        "{\LaTeX} - A Document Preparation System - User's Guide and Reference Manual",
  publisher =    {Addison Wesley},  
  year =         "1985"  
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibcheck{ownpublications}{
  \edef\authorstring{\thename{author}}  
  \IfSubStr{\authorstring}{Lamport}{%
   \skipentry
  }{}
}

% document body
\begin{document}

Cite something, this should go in the references \cite{texbook}.

Full citation of other, this should appear only here, and not in the references: \fullcite{latexbook}

\printbibliography[check=ownpublications]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot a pair of curly brackets after `\IfSubStr`: Syntax: `\IfSubStr{input1}{input2}{TRUE}{FALSE}`. If that doesn't work please provide a full minimal example.

Comment: Adding the second curly brackets does not make a difference.

Comment: And the minimal example ;-) We don't know whether you called `\printbibliography[check=ownpublications]` or not ;-)

Comment: Added. Sorry, I'm new, and took some time for figuring out where to put it:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unless you require partial string matching in names, `xstring` isn't necessary. With `backend=biber` you can identify matching entries based on the source data (e.g. the `bib` file) using the source map feature. It supports regular expressions. An example from PLK can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/4483).

With any BibTeX implementation as the backend, matching can be done on data in the `bbl` file via `\ifdefstring` (from `etoolbox`) and `\indexnames`. The latter is a `biblatex` command that applies an index formatting directive to each item in a name list. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

% Variants of each could be added
\newcommand{\firstinit}{D.~E.}
\newcommand{\firstname}{Donald~E.}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Knuth}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{byname}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{byname}{% Test could be refined
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\lastname}{#1}}
               and ( test {\ifdefstring{\firstname}{#3}}
                     or test {\ifdefstring{\firstinit}{#4}} ) }
    {\addtocategory{byname}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \indexnames[byname]{author}}

\begin{document}
\section{Knuth's books}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=book,category=byname,heading=none]
\section{Not Knuth's books}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=book,notcategory=byname,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument references (`#1`, `#3`, etc.) in `\DeclareIndexNameFormat` correspond to different parts of a name. Further details can be found in the `biblatex` manual or [this post by domwass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4082/how-do-i-include-all-authors-of-cited-works-in-an-index-of-persons/4114#4114). The data corresponding to each name element can be found in the `bbl` file. In the above example, the field `author = {Knuth, Donald E.}` is parsed as follows.

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Knuth}{K.}%
     {Donald~E.}{D.~E.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
```

Comment: By the way, I tried with

Comment: I get the following error, when using this solution: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d. […] ...   and ( test {\ifdefstring{\firstname}{#3
                                                  }}`

Comment: The argument `#1` obviously has changed to `family=Knuth, familyi=K., given=Donald~E., giveni=D.~E.`. How can I do substring matching in this?

Comment: The arguments `#1`, `#3` and `#4` have to be replace by `\namepartfamily`, `\namepartgiven` and `\namepartgiveni` respectively and `\ifdefstrequal` has to be used instead of `\ifdefstring`.

Comment: In my case this macro does not put entries to the category if the specified author is truncated by an "et al." :-\

Comment: Is there a way to count the matched entries to show it separately? E.g. "Knuth's books (6)"
Preferably when using `\printbibliography[filter=...]`

Comment: For me, this solution breaks as soon as the author that `byname` looks for is not the *first* author.