# List of publications by specific author

Tags: bibtex

I want to be able to process my CV LaTeX file and know that it has a nice list of all of my publications. I keep my global `.bib` file updated with all sorts of publications I'm interested in, and my own publications. I don't want to manually insert my publications into my `.bib` file AND to my CV LaTeX file.

How can I **automatically** create a publication list for a certain author?

Ideally I'd use `\cite{author=my_name}` and have all of my publications.

Comment: Hi Yakir, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I've removed the thanks, which is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed in the upvoting of answers that you find helpful.

Comment: This may be tricky, as it is common for BibTeX entries to use different strings between publications. i.e. my name may appear as `author = {Everitt, Mark S. and...` or  `author = {Everitt, M. and...`. In many cases an author's family name will not be unique in your database as well.

Comment: With biblatex and bibtex, this is [relatively straightforward](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509) to do. With biblatex and biber, it's probably even easier using the biber `sourcemap` option.

Answer (score 7):

For this purpose, I usually employ `bib2bib` to automatically extract all own publications into an `ownpubs.bib`, which I then use in my CV with `\cite{*}`.

The `bib2bib` utility is part of the [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) tool suite. (Note: you have to look for the **PDF** documentation, the HTML documentation does not discuss `bib2bib`!). Under Linux, it is usually preinstalled, on MacOS it is available via MacPorts, for Windows binaries are provided. The command line:

```
bib2bib -s 'year' -r --expand -c 'author : "Gagnon" or editor : "Gagnon"' -ob ownpubs.bib all.bib
```

extracts all entries with *Gagnon* part of in the `author` or the `editor` list from `all.bib` to the new file `ownpubs.bib`

Comment: This looks nice, but it will be a problem for the likes of me because I have a very similar name to another guy who has papers that are in my collection. :(

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: In that case you need to be a bit more sepecific with the filter, for instance, by including your first name or excluding certain co-authors. The bib2bib documentation has a couple of examples for the respective regular expressions.

Comment: That sounds more sophisticated than I imagined then. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest answer, provided that you use some kind of bibliography management system, is to keep a tag for your own publications. I use [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org) for example, and it automatically does this when you tell it that a paper is one you (co)authored. You can then ask for a `.bib` file with only papers tagged as your own. With the `.bib` file with just your articles, a simple `\nocite{*}` in your document will get BibTeX to use all entries in the file for the Bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

A quasi-automatic way is to use emacs+reftex.  You can search on your name and then insert all entries that match (if you have name clashes, you just need to be more clever with your regular expression).