# biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

The question I want to ask is related to the answer of this question: [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28509/biblatex-filter-out-publications-from-a-specific-author-in-the-references-dynam/28555#28555) .

My aim is to separate my bibliography into two parts : one part for a personnal bibliography, and a second one for the regular bibliography.

To do that, I use the technique of the post I cited :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=6,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

% Variants of each could be added
\newcommand{\firstname}{Donald~E.}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Knuth}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{byname}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{byname}{% Test could be refined
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\lastname}{#1}}
           and test {\ifdefstring{\firstname}{#3}}
              }
{\addtocategory{byname}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
{}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \indexnames[byname]{author}}

\begin{document}
 \section{Knuth's books}
 \begin{refsection}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography[category=byname,heading=none]
 \end{refsection}
 \section{Not Knuth's books}
 \printbibliography[notcategory=byname,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

The problem is that only the second bibliography appears, and when I remove the refsection, then all the bibtex entries of my input files are printed, separated as they should.

EDIT: the aim is to have all publications (even the ones not cited) by author knuth in the first section and all the other cited publications in the second one.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to do this using biber, I'd recommend using the `sourcemap` feature, it's cleaner than adding a category via an index format. This alters the input stream (without altering the .bib file) so that the keyword "knuth" is added to all works with matching "Knuth" as the author, which you can then filter on:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Knuth,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=knuth]
    }
  }
}

\printbibliography[keyword=knuth]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=knuth]
```

Comment: I must learn this kind of source. Awesome.

Comment: This seems neat, but the `\DeclareSourcemap` command does not seem available on my tex distribution yet, I'll test it then.

Comment: You need to update to biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0

Comment: Works like a charm now!

Comment: Is it possible to get hold of the number of references, `printbibliography` renders?

Comment: If your entries already have keywords, you need to add the `overwrite` option to `\map`.

Answer (score 11):

Here a small modification of your example. The example works only with `backend=biber`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=6,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{byname}
\newcommand*{\mknamesignature}[5]{\def#1{#2|||}}
\mknamesignature{\highlightname}{Knuth}{}{}{}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{byname}%
 {%
  \mknamesignature{\currentsignature}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \ifdefequal{\highlightname}{\currentsignature}%
    {\addtocategory{byname}{\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    {}%
}

\AtDataInput{%
  \indexnames[byname]{author}}

\begin{document}
 \section{Knuth's books}
 \begin{refsection}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography[category=byname,heading=none]
 \end{refsection}

 \section{Not Knuth's books}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography[notcategory=byname,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me: there is still no citation in the first category.

Comment: really? Did you run with biber?

Comment: @Pascal: Which version of biblatex do you use?

Comment: Ah sorry, I had not seen that it should be ran with biber. Biber doesn't work currently on my distro, I would prefer a solution without it, if you have one.

Comment: @Pascal: I don't know a way with bibtex? Which problems do you have with `biber`?

Comment: It gives me this message error when I try to run it : data source /tmp/par-pascal/cache-93fb3b092450140ffa13bb862af563c85b798cc9/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 21.

Comment: @Pascal Remove the named folder. It's a known problem.

Comment: Thanks it works now, but there is still a small problem : I cite articles which fall in the first category, and for these, the hyperref link does not work. Do you know a workaround for this ?

Comment: @Pascal: I would ask a new question. In a trice I have no idea.,

Comment: how did you mix two styles in one document?