# How to only cite references by a certain author

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65114/biblatex-separating-publications-of-a-specific-author-in-the-bibliography)

I have a BibTeX file that includes my own publications as well as many others. I'd like to use this file without modification in my CV, but in the references I only want to show my own publications.

Can I do this with biber/BibLaTeX?

Comment: One way to do this with bibtex is to have *two* bibfiles. One for own publications and one for everyone else. For own CV do `\bibliography{ownpubs}` and `\nocite{*}` and for other purposes can do `\bibliography{ownpubs,otherpubs}` and `\cite{}` from both lists.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing this. I was intentionally trying to avoid it.