# How to print a bibliography for a particular author only?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

Background: I have all bibliographic entries in one giant .bib file.  In my CV, I'd like to have a section that lists all my articles and another section that lists all my conference presentations.  My current approach is this:  I tag my own entries with the keyword "own" and then use biblatex:

```
\printbibliography[type=article,keyword=own,heading="Articles"]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,keyword=own,heading="Conference Presentations"]
```

This approach has two drawbacks.  First, I have to tag all my entries and it happened that I missed some.  Second, I have to nocite all my entries, which is another great opportunity to make mistakes.

The first problem can be addressed using bib2bib, which allows me to extract my own articles from the big .bib file by specifying a filter for the `author` field.  However, I was wondering if there is a simpler solution using only tools within LaTeX.  `\printbibliography` already seems to have some filtering facility but from reading the manual I couldn't figure out how to filter entries based on the values of their fields.

Comment: The filtering is not explained in detail in the manual but we have some nice answers here already, does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65114/biblatex-separating-publications-of-a-specific-author-in-the-bibliography?rq=1) answer cover you question?

Comment: Thanks, Alex, that answers the first part.  The second part about the nociting is still open.

Comment: @tmalsburg In that post you should use PLK's answer, which is pretty much the same as Henrique's below. If you insist on using BibTeX, the question links to a solution. For citing, why not just use `\nocite{*}`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete and redundant answer; since [PLK's previous answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/5872) already answer the first requirement (as pointed by Alexander and Audrey), I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: @Audrey I can't use `\nocite{*}` because the same document also contains a list of other references at the end (it's one document that contains my CV in one section and a research proposal in another section).  If I would nocite everything, the final list of references would include all entries in my database.

Comment: @tmalsburg Then use reference sections as in the posts you've already been pointed to. The section containing the CV can access the source file via `\nocite{*}`. The proposal in another section cites as usual.

Comment: @henrique Since PLK's answer doesn't give a complete document, I don't think it is necessary to delete your answer - a revision including reference sections would be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use regexp to map a `keyword = {own},` field to all entries with a given pattern in `author` field via `\DelclareSourcemap`, as shown in [PLK's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/5872) to [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114) (there's also an example in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) that adds a keyword to every entry with a given title, check §4.5.2.). Something like:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Kant,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=own]
    }
  }
}
```

After this, you could use `\printbibliography[keyword={own}]` *within a `refsection` environment* in order to have all entries marked with your keyword (called via `\nocite{*}`) printed, like shown in [Marco Daniel's answer to the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65118):

```
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={These are my Works}]
\end{refsection}
```

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Kant,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=own]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
Hi, I'm Kant.
\autocites{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,companion}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={These are my Works}]
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own,title={These are awesome works by other people I like}]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

#### * Edit: I have removed the `\regexp` from `match=Kant` inside the `\DeclareSourceMap` since it's not needed.

Comment: I used this solution but with two modifications: 1.) I used `\map[overwrite=true]` because otherwise entries that already have keywords are ignored. 2.) I didn't replace the pre-existing keywords with `own` but appended `own` to the list of keywords.  This can be done with the following command: `\step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, own}, append]`  This was necessary because I also use other keywords to select the relevant entries.  Thanks for providing me with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem like tmalsburg with the current EXPORT function for the .bib file of CITAVI.

The issue is CITAVE generally uses a ";" as a separator
while LATEX uses a ","

so if you EXPORT from CITAVI the keywordlines in the .bib look like:

```
 keywords = {Result CV;wearable},
```

But what you would need is:

```
 keywords = {Result CV,wearable},
```

So with the direct export result you can select the keyword "Result CV;wearable" in latex then it prints you the respective reference... so it sees this as one keyword...

I haven't found a solution in citavi to change this, but will report the issue to them.

**The best solution I could give at the moment is:**

Assign your keywords in Citavi

Export .bib file from Citavi

Open the .bib file with notepad++ and in the replace function do the following

Find what: `^(.*keywords.*);`

Replace with:`$1,`

Run repeatedly until you get 0 occurrences.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: the separator can be changed: the export definition in Citavi can be configured to suit your needs.
 
Go to File > Export > BibTeX  and click on the blue "Edit BibTeX export definition..." 
 
First you can define the mapping of the reference types, then you can define the fields for each reference type, and in the third window, you can define the "Keyword separator"

Replace the ";" by a comma, here and click "Next". Save the BibTeX export definition by giving it a name,  "BibTeX [comma between keywords].
You do not need to save the "export preset" in the next window.