# auto generate citation list for specific author

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm currently putting together a CV and I am looking for a way to automate the process. I have a central bibtex database that stores 500+ entries, and I want to automatically import and create a bibliography for only the entries that have my name in the `author` field. When using biber, I am aware of the option to use `\printbibliography` with optional inputs to filter based on the type of the entry:

```
\printbibliography[type=article]
\printbibliography[type=article]
```

Is there any similar procedure that allows you to search the `author` fields? Or a process that amounts to:

```
\printbibliography[author=John Doe]
```

Comment: The smart thing to do would be to use the `keywords` field in those entries and then use that in your `\printbibliography` command (e.g., `\printbibligraphy[keyword=XYZ]`). You can dynamically create such keywords using biblatex/biber's  `\DeclareSourcemap`, but depending on the name, you might get lots of false positives. (A name with 'John' or 'Smith', e.g., would not be ideal.)

Comment: Please see [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864), [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864), [How to print a bibliography for a particular author only?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125744/35864). See the second part of my answer to [Customizing citations and the list of publications depending on the author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286471/35864) on how to use hashes for name recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. Based on the recomended answers, and some extra browsing, I've pieced together a MWE that does exactly what I need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,refsection=section,sorting=ydnt,
           defernumbers=true,maxnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%----------------Sourcemap to create keyword based on author-------------------%
%Search and replace "Knuth" and "NOTKnuth" with the desired author name
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Knuth,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=Knuth]    
      }  
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
                      notmatch=Knuth,
                      final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=NOTKnuth]
    }
  }
}

%------------------Create bib sections for numbering --------------------------%
\defbibnote{books}{}
\defbibnote{other}{}
\defbibnote{DifAuthors}{}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}   
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

%---------------------------Begin Document-------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Knuth Books},prenote=books,type=book,keyword=Knuth,resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[title=Other,prenote=other,nottype=book,nottype=article,nottype=patent,keyword=Knuth,resetnumbers=true]

%Other authors: Just to make sure it is properly sorting the files
\printbibliography[title={DifferentAuthors},prenote=DifAuthors,type=article,keyword=NOTKnuth,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works really well for different file types, and handled my 500+ reference library, so thanks again for the pointers!

Comment: Note that you might not need `NOTKnuth` after all you can just use `notkeyword=knuth` instead of `keyword=knuth`. This is more or less what PLK did in [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/35864)

Comment: Agreed. I merely wanted to show how to nest multiple logical statement like that. In this way you could, for example, select multiple authors.

Comment: Is it possible to get hold of the number of entries `printbibliography` prints to embed that number in the heading, e.g. "Knuth's books (7)"?