# Have two lists of references, each ordered by name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to have two lists of references: One for a specific author (let's say Victor) and another for all other authors. Based on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125744/), I came up with this example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=ynt,%sorting=none,
  sortcites=true,
  maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125744/
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{\step[fieldsource=author,match=Victor,final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=victor]}}}

\defbibcheck{victors}{%
  \ifkeyword{victor}{}{\skipentry}}%
\defbibcheck{notvictors}{%
  \ifkeyword{victor}{\skipentry}{}}%


\begin{document}
% \nocite{sorace,padhye} % Possible fix?
Some items are cited \cite{sorace} More items \cite{aksin,vazques-de-parga,wassenberg}
Even more item \cite{padhye} and \cite{almendro,kowalik,laufenberg}.
\medskip

\printbibliography[title={The Victors},check=victors]
\printbibliography[title={And the Victors not},check=notvictors]
\end{document}
```

which works well. However, I would like to have the citation numbers be increasing across the two lists. There are two cases I am particularly interested in:

- `sorting=none`. In this case, since sorting is based on citation order, I could force the output I am after by adding `\nocite{sorace,padhye}` at the very beginning. However, I am wondering if there's a way to avoid having to maintain a list of citations at the beginning of the document (or alternatively, is there a way to call `nocite` on all references with a particular keyword?).
- `sorting=ynt`. In this case, I want the order within each list to be `ynt`, but the citation number must be increasing across lists.

Is either of these cases possible to resolve?

Comment: Regardless of the `sorting` setting you can get increasing numbers in disjoint bibliographies (like this one) with the option `defernumbers=true,`.

Comment: Yes, `defernumbers=true` works exactly as I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of the selected `sorting` template, most split bibliography setups (that are non-overlapping) benefit from `defernumbers=true,`. That option will make sure that the numbering of your references follows the appearance in the bibliography and not the global sort order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=ynt,%sorting=none,
  defernumbers=true,
  maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125744/
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{\step[fieldsource=author,match=Victor,final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=victor]}}}

\defbibcheck{victors}{%
  \ifkeyword{victor}{}{\skipentry}}%
\defbibcheck{notvictors}{%
  \ifkeyword{victor}{\skipentry}{}}%


\begin{document}
% \nocite{sorace,padhye} % Possible fix?
Some items are cited \cite{sorace} More items \cite{aksin,vazques-de-parga,wassenberg}
Even more item \cite{padhye} and \cite{almendro,kowalik,laufenberg}.
\medskip

\printbibliography[title={The Victors},check=victors]
\printbibliography[title={And the Victors not},check=notvictors]
\end{document}
```

[image: Increasing numbers in bibliography]

`defernumbers` uses the `.aux` file and may therefore need additional LaTeX runs (if more runs are required, this will be mentioned in the `.log` file). Sometimes the numbering might "get stuck" if you change sort options or have (unrelated) LaTeX errors, in that case it may help to delete the `.aux` file (and for good measure also the `.bbl` and `.bcf`) and recompile.