# Simple way of setting up two bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I want to split the bibliography into two parts, with one containing only works by a certain author and another all the rest.

I tried figuring out how to do this with `biblatex` but got tangled up. What is the simplest way of proceeding? This is a one-off project so I don't mind a workaround solution if it's easy to set up.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But I am trying to do something I don't know how! This is not debugging, I just don't know how to do this...

Comment: The minimum example is a starter for other users, such that they don't have to do it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know about the importance of MWE. But in this particular case I don't see how can I provide one. It's not that I am doing X hoping to get Y but getting Z - I have no idea at this stage how to do X at all, so I have nothing to post, alas.

Comment: You could do something like http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography/4408#4408 of course with your `biblatex` setup as it is.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is with biblatex. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65114/biblatex-separating-publications-of-a-specific-author-in-the-bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

With `biblatex` you can create a filter for any field in your `.bib` files, and print separate bibliographies for these. Here I filter by keyword, but you could also filter by author.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{article.bib}
@Book{Abc,
  author=   {Abc, D.},
  title=    {Primary Source},
  year=     1492,
  keywords= {1}
}

@Book{Efg,
  author=   {Efg, H.},
  title=    {Secondary Source},
  year=     1942,
  keywords= {2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{article.bib}
\defbibfilter{primary}{keyword=1}
\defbibfilter{secondary}{keyword=2}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\section{Bibliography}

\subsection{Primary Sources}

\printbibliography[heading=none, filter=primary]

\subsection{Secondary Sources}

\printbibliography[heading=none, filter=secondary]

\end{document}
```

[image]