# Highlight one entry in bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, memoir

In my bibliography, which I'm writing using bibtex, I'd like to highlight a special item and place it on the top of the bibliography, even though I'm using chronological order (sorting=ynt), since it's the main reference of my girlfriend's thesis. Is there any way to do it?

Some additional information: I'm using `memoir` as the document class, I'm including `biblatex` as this:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    citestyle=verbose-ibid,
    style=verbose-ibid,
    sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
```

and I'm including the bibliography like this:

```
\printbibliography
```

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: I don't recommend using `backend=bibtex` with `biblatex` any more. You should use `biber`.  But what you're asking seems like a very odd thing to do. But it's common to separate things into primary and secondary sources, and this is easy to do with `biblatex`.  See [Simple way of setting up two bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201994/2693) and [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/2693). The latter approach can be applied to any category, not just authors.

Comment: I second Alan's comment as to this being odd (I'd say it would probably be harder, not easier, to find it). But if you really want to have the thesis first in an otherwise chronological bibliography, you could try the `sortyear` entryfield, setting, let's say, `sortyear = {1500},` in your girlfriend's thesis bibentry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sortkey` or `presort` to sort a particular entry before all others. With `sorting=nyt` you could use `presort={0}`.

```
@book{aardvark,
  author = {Aardvark, Anne},
  titel  = {Now, this is Aardvark},
  year   = {2012},
}
@book{wombat,
  author  = {Wombat, Wilbur},
  titel   = {This is Wombat},
  year    = {2017},
  presort = {0},
}
```

---

I can, however, not recommend just (seemingly arbitrarily) seamlessly sorting one entry out of order before all others.

You could instead split the bibliography.

Statically via `keywords` in the `.bib` file

```
@book{aardvark,
  author   = {Aardvark, Anne},
  titel    = {Now, this is Aardvark},
  year     = {2012},
  keywords = {secondary},
}
@book{wombat,
  author   = {Wombat, Wilbur},
  titel    = {This is Wombat},
  year     = {2017},
  keywords = {primary},
}
```

and filter

```
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, heading=subbibliography, title={Primary}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, heading=subbibliography, title={Secondary}]
```

You could also only set `keywords` for `primary` and filter all others via `notkeyword`.

```
\printbibliography[keyword=primary]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary]
```

Or dynamically via `categories`

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{wombat}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[category=important, heading=subbibliography, title={Primary}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=important, heading=subbibliography, title={Secondary}]
```

There are even more possibilities to split the bibliography, for example by author [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864)