# Highlight citations of works a specific author contributed to

Tags: biblatex

I'm thinking a solution should exist already, but I'm unable to find it... so, how could I highlight citations to a work a specific author contributed to?

It's a bit like printing the name of a certain author in bold in the bibliography, but this doesn't work in citations where the author one wants to highlight is hidden in the "et al."

For highlighting an author in the bibliography, I use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/50288) with the `\boldname` command.

The highlighted author's name might have non-standard characters, so I use a silly example author, Därwin. The behaviour I want would be like this:
[image: example]

Where to start? Add a keyword and change all cite commands by calling `\renewbibmacro*{cite}{...}`? And what to put there ?

Here's a MWE, I haven't really done anything, but at least it should show the options I'm using (for the sake of conciseness, I left the `\boldname` definition out, but I could add it if it is relevant).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

 \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,%
 minbibnames=15,%
 maxbibnames=15,%
 backend=biber]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @Book{Darwin.84,
   author =      {C. D\"{a}rwin},
   title =   {The different forms of flowers on plants of the same species},
   publisher =   {John Murray},
   address =      {London},
   edition =      2,
   year =    1884}

 @ARTICLE{Davies.pnas04,
 AUTHOR = {Davies, T. J. AND Barraclough, T. G. AND Chase, M. W. AND Soltis, P. S. AND Soltis, D. E. AND D\"{a}rwin, C.},
 TITLE = {D\"{a}rwin's abominable mystery: {Insights} from a supertree of the angiosperms.},
 JOURNAL = {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A.},
 VOLUME = {101},
 PAGES = {1904--1909},
 YEAR = {2004},
 MONTH = Feb,
 NUMBER = {7}
 }

 @ARTICLE{Vamosi.el10,
 AUTHOR = {Vamosi, J. C. AND Vamosi, S. M.},
 TITLE = {Key innovations within a geographical context in flowering plants: towards resolving {D\"{a}rwin}'s abominable mystery.},
 JOURNAL = {Ecol. Lett.},
 VOLUME = {13},
 PAGES = {1270--1279},
 YEAR = {2010},
 MONTH = Oct,
 NUMBER = {10}
 }

 \end{filecontents}
 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \makeatother

 \begin{document}


 \citet{Darwin.84} a souvent été cité, par exemple par  
 \citet{Davies.pnas04,Vamosi.el10}.

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864) and [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864). Then you only need to make sure cites from a particular category or with a certain keyword are highlighted.

Comment: See also [Customizing citations and the list of publications depending on the author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286471/35864).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with the last link? Or do you needs some more pointers?

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question as a duplicate of [Customizing citations and the list of publications depending on the author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286471/35864) in due time, if you do not complain.