# Line breaks in underlined citations

Tags: biblatex, soul, ulem

I've been looking for a solution to [automatically highlight citations to the works of a specific author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283251/50288)  using biblatex, but the question is still unanswered and I'm lacking time at the moment to investigate it myself.

Anyway, I've been doing it manually by underlining the citations I want to highlight (author names are printed in small caps, so I can't just emphasize them). However, this causes overfull lines as the underlining doesn't allow line breaks in the citations. I've used `\underline`, `\uline` from the `ulem` package ; both don't break lines. 
`ul` from the `soul` package causes an error, due to interference with `biblatex` ?

Is there a way to underline citations that allows line breaks ?

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
 %\usepackage{soul}
 \usepackage{ulem}

 \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,%
 backend=biber]{biblatex}

 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @Book{Darwin.84,
   author =      {C. D\"{a}rwin},
   title =   {The different forms of flowers on plants of the same species},
   publisher =   {John Murray},
   address =      {London},
   edition =      2,
   year =    1884}

 @ARTICLE{Davies.pnas04,
 AUTHOR = {Davies, T. J. AND Barraclough, T. G. AND Chase, M. W. AND Soltis, P. S. AND Soltis, D. E. AND D\"{a}rwin, C.},
 TITLE = {D\"{a}rwin's abominable mystery: {Insights} from a supertree of the angiosperms.},
 JOURNAL = {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A.},
 VOLUME = {101},
 PAGES = {1904--1909},
 YEAR = {2004},
 MONTH = Feb,
 NUMBER = {7}
 }

 @ARTICLE{Vamosi.el10,
 AUTHOR = {Vamosi, J. C. AND Vamosi, S. M.},
 TITLE = {Key innovations within a geographical context in flowering plants: towards resolving {D\"{a}rwin}'s abominable mystery.},
 JOURNAL = {Ecol. Lett.},
 VOLUME = {13},
 PAGES = {1270--1279},
 YEAR = {2010},
 MONTH = Oct,
 NUMBER = {10}
 }

 \end{filecontents}
 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


 \makeatother

 \begin{document}


 \citet{Davies.pnas04,Vamosi.el10} cite \uline{\citet{Darwin.84}}.

 %\citet{Davies.pnas04,Vamosi.el10} cite \ul{\citet{Darwin.84}}.

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to underline the citations in paragraphs, or do you want to underline titles in References?

Comment: I want to underline "Darwin (1884)" in the text. I just added the bibliography to see where the lines ends, but I should have used lipsum for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Underlining is very hard for TeX. In particular `\underline` can never break. The commands `\uline` and `\ul` (from `ulem` and `soul`) lift this restriction, but at a cost of requiring their arguments to be comparatively simple. Complicated macros like `\cite` either don't allow for line breaks (because they contain grouping) or don't work at all.

The only way I see to solve this is to use LuaTeX to underline text using [Paul Isambert's `\underline`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf). See also [How to underline whole bibitem in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435962/35864)

The MWE must be compiled with LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\newattribute{\ulattr}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
local RULE = node.id("rule")
local GLUE = node.id("glue")
local KERN = node.id("kern")
local ULATTR = luatexbase.attributes["ulattr"]

function get_lines(head)
  for line in node.traverse_id(HLIST, head) do
    underline(line.list, line.glue_order,
      line.glue_set, line.glue_sign)
  end
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                                  "get_lines")
  return head
end

local function good_item(item)
  if item.id == GLUE and
    (item.subtype == node.subtype("leftskip")
     or item.subtype == node.subtype("rightskip")
     or item.subtype == node.subtype("parfillskip")) then
      return false
  else
    return true
  end
end

function underline(head, order, ratio, sign)
  local item = head
  while item do
    if node.has_attribute(item, ULATTR)
      and good_item(item) then
        local item_line = node.new(RULE)
        item_line.depth = tex.sp("1.4pt")
        item_line.height = tex.sp("-1pt")
        local end_node = item
        while end_node.next and
          good_item(end_node.next) and
          node.has_attribute(end_node.next, ULATTR) do
            end_node = end_node.next
        end
        item_line.width = node.dimensions
          (ratio, sign, order, item, end_node.next)
        local item_kern = node.new(KERN, 1)
        item_kern.kern = -item_line.width
        node.insert_after(head, end_node,        
                          item_kern)
        node.insert_after(head, item_kern,
                          item_line)
        item = end_node.next
    else
      item = item.next
    end
  end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\luaunderline}[1]{%
  \quitvmode
  \setattribute{\ulattr}{1}%
  #1%
  \unsetattribute{\ulattr}%
  \directlua{%
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                               get_lines, "get_lines")}%
}

\newcommand{\luaunderlineswitch}{%
  \quitvmode\setattribute{\ulattr}{1}%
  \directlua{%
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                               get_lines, "get_lines")}%
}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{sigfridsson,nussbaum} cite \underline{\textcite{sigfridsson}}.

  \textcite{sigfridsson,nussbaum} cite \uline{\textcite{sigfridsson}}.

%  \textcite{sigfridsson,nussbaum} cite \ul{\textcite{sigfridsson}}.% <- gives a error

  \textcite{sigfridsson,nussbaum} cite \luaunderline{\textcite{sigfridsson}}.

  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]