# How to underline whole bibitem in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, ulem, underline

I want to underline whole bibitem when using biblatex. I tried `\AtEveryBibitem{\uline}` but failed.

What I want to do:

[image: underline]

Comment: It is quite difficult to underline paragraphs, and if they contain complicated commands like the biblatex code or even url's even more. So better avoid it. If you really need it your best bets are probably tikz or lualatex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is going to be very hard with `biblatex` because `\uline` can not deal with complicated macros in its argument. But due to the way `biblatex` works we would inevitably end up feeding extremely complicated macros to `\uline`. Simple things like `\uline{\printtext{foo}}` seem to work fine, but `\uline{\printfield{title}}` already broke when the title was to be typeset in quotation marks. All hell broke lose and line breaking failed (because of grouping) even with `\uline{\printnames{author}\setunit{\addspace}\printfield[emph]{title}}`. The "real" argument to `\uline` would be much more complex.

So I guess this is one of these situations where BibTeX can do better. The way `.bst` files work means that `\uline` can operate almost directly on the raw text. If we additionally avoid grouping and other font formatting commands, we can get quite a pleasant result.

The general idea will be similar for most `.bst` files, but the actual implementation of course differs. Under https://gist.github.com/moewew/4a4beb11a35ed43541cc8f238f7deca8 you can find a modified version of `plain.bst` that underlines entire entries.

The major work was done by replacing the function `output.bibitem` with

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  "\uline{" write$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

the new line was just `"\uline{" write$`.

The function `fin.entry` was changed to

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
}
```

here, the `"}" write$` is new.

In the linked file the `emphasize` function is turned into a no-op and all other references to `\em` have been removed as well. This avoids grouping and allows `ulem` to break lines properly.

Save the new file as `plain-ul.bst` and use it as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service and a very very very very long subtitle that hopefully shows us a line break},
  year    = {1980},
  publisher = {BBC},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{plain-ul}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to continue using `biblatex` you might want to looking into alternative ways to produce underlining. I would guess that an approach with `ulem` is doomed to failure (at least if you don't rewrite the bibliography drivers with low-level commands).

As suggested by Ulrike in the comments, LuaLaTeX may be able to help you here.

**Update**

Things are much easier now with Marcel Krüger's `lua-ul` package.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lua-ul}

\makeatletter
% internal name from lua-ul
\AtEveryBibitem{\@underLine}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\underLine{Lorem} ipsum \underLine{dolor} sit amet.
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

[Paul Isambert's TUGboat article *Three things you can do with LuaTeX that
would be extremely painful otherwise*](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf) implements an underline that is also usable for us here. With a few modifications the eight-year-old code still works and gives us

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newattribute{\ulattr}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
local RULE = node.id("rule")
local GLUE = node.id("glue")
local KERN = node.id("kern")
local ULATTR = luatexbase.attributes["ulattr"]

function get_lines(head)
  for line in node.traverse_id(HLIST, head) do
    underline(line.list, line.glue_order,
      line.glue_set, line.glue_sign)
  end
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                                  "get_lines")
  return head
end

local function good_item(item)
  if item.id == GLUE and
    (item.subtype == node.subtype("leftskip")
     or item.subtype == node.subtype("rightskip")
     or item.subtype == node.subtype("parfillskip")) then
      return false
  else
    return true
  end
end

function underline(head, order, ratio, sign)
  local item = head
  while item do
    if node.has_attribute(item, ULATTR)
      and good_item(item) then
        local item_line = node.new(RULE)
        item_line.depth = tex.sp("1.4pt")
        item_line.height = tex.sp("-1pt")
        local end_node = item
        while end_node.next and
          good_item(end_node.next) and
          node.has_attribute(end_node.next, ULATTR) do
            end_node = end_node.next
        end
        item_line.width = node.dimensions
          (ratio, sign, order, item, end_node.next)
        local item_kern = node.new(KERN, 1)
        item_kern.kern = -item_line.width
        node.insert_after(head, end_node,        
                          item_kern)
        node.insert_after(head, item_kern,
                          item_line)
        item = end_node.next
    else
      item = item.next
    end
  end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\luaunderline}[1]{%
  \quitvmode
  \setattribute{\ulattr}{1}%
  #1%
  \unsetattribute{\ulattr}%
  \directlua{%
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                               get_lines, "get_lines")}%
}

\newcommand{\luaunderlineswitch}{%
  \quitvmode\setattribute{\ulattr}{1}%
  \directlua{%
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                               get_lines, "get_lines")}%
}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\begingroup\luaunderlineswitch}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentrypunct\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\luaunderline{Lorem} ipsum {\luaunderlineswitch dolor} sit amet.
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A big thank you to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for suggesting many improvements in the comments and helping me understand the code a bit better through these improvements.

---

Many people (especially on this site) consider underlining to be a relic of the type writer age and would suggest other ways to highlight text. Try bold or add a symbol to highlight an entry...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also think that the underline is outdated, and I will not use it if it is not the school's request. I don't have to use ulem, but it would be better to use biblatex. Is there any alternative ways to produce underlining in biblatex?

Comment: @GenkunAbe The question is how badly does your school want underlining? Can't you persuade them to accept an alternative (bold face)? The three standard solution for underlining are `\underline` (does not break across lines and so can't be used for long stretches of text, i.e. not usable here), `ulem`'s `\uline` which can't deal with complex arguments and `soul`'s `\ul` which is similarly bad at handling complex arguments (in fact `ulem` fared better than `soul`, but is still not usable). So these standard way's can't get you anywhere. ...

Comment: ... You could look into TikZ or LuaLaTeX. I certainly don't have enough expertise in these areas to be able to cook up a functioning solution.

Comment: For luatex there is some code here https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf. But it is from 2010 and would need some adaption - some things have changed in the mean time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you *very* much for that hint! It seems to work with only a few modifications, but I can't really say that I understand everything that is going on even after skimming the article.

Comment: @moewe wow. I'm impressed.

Comment: But it would be better to replace the hardcoded attribute register number 100 by one allocated with \newattribute.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the comment. I hope it is better now. I'm not very familiar with all of this. Is there a good reference for LuaLaTeX coding? I had `ltluatex.dtx` and http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf open, but I still had to piece things together from several other sources as well.

Comment: Very neat! A pity I cannot upvote again.

Comment: looks good. One could also replace the subtype numbers 8,9 and 15 by `node.subtype("leftskip")` , `node.subtype("rightskip")`  and `node.subtype("parfillskip")`

Comment: @gusbrs Of course I do, this is embarrassing... Thank you very much for catching this. (I had 'not only ... but also' there before and decided to get rid of it when I rewrote a bit of the sentence, but the 'not' stuck around). Sorry Ulrike.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. But it is not only a relic. In case of a  whole reference  underlined  is a tremendously ugly format (of course, only IMHO).