# How to underline text with in-text citation with wrapping?

Tags: citing, ulem, underline

The line of text I want to underline includes in-text citation. My problem is that `\uline` only works on this line when I use `\mbox`(I get an error without `\mbox`), which makes it impossible to wrap the text. Note that when I remove the `\cite` command, `\uline` works perfectly. How can I underline and wrap text that includes citation?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{     hermes2008a,
  author    = {Hermes, Juliet C. and Reason, C. J C},
  journal   = {Journal of Geophysical Research: Oceans},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {1--10},
  title     = {{Annual cycle of the South Indian Ocean
          (Seychelles-Chagos) thermocline ridge in a regional ocean
          model}},
  volume    = {113},
  year      = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=18mm,right=18mm,top=27mm,bottom=27mm}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{usebib}
\bibinput{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{\uline{~\mbox{\cite{hermes2008a}: ~\mbox{\usebibentry{hermes2008a}{title}}}}}

\subsubsection*{\uline{Hermes and Reason (2008): Annual cycle of the South Indian Ocean (Seychelles-Chagos) thermocline ridge in a regional ocean model}}


\subsubsection*{\cite{hermes2008a}: \usebibentry{hermes2008a}{title}}


\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the reason for using `\subsubsection` here?

Comment: Underlining is incredibly hard for TeX (and some would say typographically dubious), so if you can avoid it at all you should do that. `ulem`'s `\uline` and `soul`'s `\ul` have severe limitations in what they can accept as arguments: Plain text and some simple macros are usually fine, but more complicated macros like `\cite` often either cause errors or don't come out as expected (no underlining, no line breaks). The contents of some boxes cannot be broken across lines, that's why you can't get a line break here. BTW: The use of `\subsection` does not make the problem easier.

Comment: In my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435962/35864 I adapted LuaLaTeX code by Paul Isambert to implement a more robust `\luaunderline` command that can accept `\cite` etc. in its argument. but of course that requires LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe what about utilizing `\underline{}`?

Comment: @naphaneal `\underline` does not do line breaks. The result will be similar to the first line in the screenshot. That's one of the reasons why `ulem`'s and `soul`'s underline commands exist in the first place: They allow for line breaks.