# How to underline CJK with soul?

Tags: cjk, soul, underline

I was using `soul` to underline text.
It works until I tried to underline some CJK text.

When I have

```
\def \mytest {测试test very long text blah blah blah ...}
\ul\mytest
```

in the document, it complains:
`Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.`

I also tried `\CJKunderline`. But it does not auto-wrap for this long text.

Comment: There is https://ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8, which might help (I didn't test). Do you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? But as always: *Underlining is hard* in TeX and `soul` as well as `ulem` have restrictions in what their underlining macros can accept as input. It may well be that neither can accept CJK characters without exploding. You already know about Paul Isambert's LuaLaTeX underlining code that should work here (again I didn't test), but of course requires LuaLaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435962/35864).

Comment: I tried soulutf8, with XeLaTeX. And It does not help. But thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Run the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\def \mytest {测试test very long text blah blah blah ...}
\ul\mytest
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have `\usepackage{xeCJK}` after `\usepackage{fontspec}`, and the same complain remains.

Comment: I checked the document of xeCJK. It uses `fontspec` inside. I doubt `soul` is not compatible with `xeCJK`.

Comment: yes, seems so. It is the way how `xeCJK` redefines character setting

Comment: Well, I guess I cannot get rid of xeCJK. I use it to set font.

Comment: fontsetting can also be done with fontspec. But I am not an CJK expert ...

Comment: Yes, but xeCJK provides `\setCJKmainfont`, `\setCJKfamilyfont` etc. I can set/change font for CJK text only. I don't if `fontspec` can and how to  do it.

Comment: You can define a font family, eg `\newfontfamily\NotoJP{Noto Sans CJK JP}` and using this font with `{\Noto .... some text ....}`

Comment: Yes. But I can set main font for CJK and non-CJK independently with xeCJK. As CJK and non-CJK text are likely mixed together in a document, I have to change font for them now and then without xeCJK. It seems not a good way.