# Color and thickness of lines (backaddress underlined and subject underlined) in scrlttr2

Tags: color, scrlttr2

I am trying to change the colors of some lines in scrlttr2, especially the lines below the backaddress and the subject (visible with the `backaddress = underlined` and `subject = underlined` options). I know I can change the color of the `fromrule` with `\setkomafont{fromrule}{\color{red}}`.

When I use `\setkomafont{backaddress}{\color{red}}` only the address's color changes, but the line stays black. With `\setkomafont{subject}{\color{red}}`, as expected, the whole subject turns red, but I only want the line below the subject to change.

And I would also like to adapt the thickness of the lines.

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass[
  fromalign = right,
  fromrule = aftername,
  backaddress = underlined,
  subject = underlined,
  subject = centered,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{xcolor}  

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstr. 1\\ 12345 Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{subject}{Here comes the subject.}

\setkomafont{fromrule}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\color{red}\itshape}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{subject}{\color{red}}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{fromrulethickness}{2pt}
\@setplength{fromrulewidth}{9cm}
\makeatother

\begin{letter}{Somebody}
  \opening{To whom it may concern,}
  here comes some text
  \closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that is not intended. So there is no font element which could be set or changed by `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`, respectively. Both `backaddress=underline` and `subject=underline` uses `\underline` for the rule below the element. I do not know how the thickness of such a rule can be changed.

So the following suggestions are **only workarounds**, if you really need colored backaddress and/or subject rules in a letter.

---

To change only the color of the rules, you can redefine `\backaddr@format` and `\subject@format`. Both are internal commands, so the redefinitions can break in the future. Additionally they will be overwritten if you set later `backaddress=plain`, `backaddress=underlined`, `subject=plain` or `subject=underlined`.

```
\renewcommand{\backaddr@format}[1]{\color{green}\underline{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subject@format}[1]{\color{blue}\underline{\usekomafont{subject}#1}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  fromalign = right,
  fromrule = aftername,
  %backaddress = underlined,% <- default
  subject = underlined,
  subject = centered,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setkomafont{fromrule}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\color{red}\itshape}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{lettersubject}{\color{red}}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{fromrulethickness}{2pt}
\@setplength{fromrulewidth}{9cm}

\renewcommand{\backaddr@format}[1]{\color{green}\underline{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subject@format}[1]{\color{blue}\underline{\usekomafont{subject}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstr. 1\\ 12345 Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{subject}{Here comes the subject.}

\begin{letter}{Somebody}
  \opening{To whom it may concern,}
  here comes some text
  \closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to change the thickness of the lines too, you can use:

```
\setkomavar{subject}{\setulcolor{blue}\setul{.65ex}{2pt}\ul{Here comes the subject.}}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\setulcolor{green}\ul{Max Mustermann, Hauptstr. 1, 12345 Musterhausen}}
```

The both keys `backaddress` and `subject` must be set to `plain`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  fromalign = right,
  fromrule = aftername,
  backaddress = plain,% <- plain
  %subject = plain,% <- changed, but plain is default
  subject = centered,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}% <- added

\setkomafont{fromrule}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\color{red}\itshape}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{lettersubject}{\color{red}}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{fromrulethickness}{2pt}
\@setplength{fromrulewidth}{9cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstr. 1\\ 12345 Musterhausen}



 \setkomavar{subject}{\setulcolor{blue}\setul{.65ex}{2pt}\ul{Here comes the subject.}}
    \setkomavar{backaddress}{\setulcolor{green}\ul{Max Mustermann, Hauptstr. 1, 12345 Musterhausen}}

\begin{letter}{Somebody}
  \opening{To whom it may concern,}
  here comes some text
  \closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exactly what I was looking for. Just one little follow-up question. When I use `\enquote{...}` from the `csquotes` package within the subject, I get a runaway argument. Is that a bug in `csquotes`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443055/43317.