# Color text: Soul - reconstruction failed with font switching

Tags: color, soul

I want to color my text and followed [this sample code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312583/48642). Now I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage{xcolor} % for highlighting AND background images-color!!!
\usepackage{soul} %for usage of style attributes - background color
\newcommand{\cText}[3][RGB]{%
    \begingroup
    \definecolor{hlcolor}{#1}{#2}\sethlcolor{hlcolor}%
    \hl{#3}%
    \endgroup
}
\definecolor{RGB2}{RGB}{35, 111, 161}
\definecolor{HTML3}{HTML}{bfedd2}
\soulregister\LARGE7
\begin{document}
Test z% translated tag: span
{\cText[HTML]{7e8c8d}
    {wecks U
%       {\LARGE{}msetzung von größeren } % [2] <== not working
%       {\color{HTML3}{}
        {\LARGE{}HTML}
%           Text
%       }-Entities \&<
    }
} 

\end{document}
```

As soon as I try to uncomment [2] I get the error `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed` The same applies for uncommenting the other following lines.

What to do better? Or is there a *better* approach to color text - especially when the size and background might change?

Comment: can you use lualatex? Then switch to the lua-ul package - much more robust.

Comment: Yeah, I am using luatex 1.12. Therefore the question how would a solution look like? To my understanding I need xcolor for changing the text tcolor and soul for highlighting. So I guess that's not a blocking issue to have different colors used.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533380/2388. Or read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for being persistent. But neither the  sample referred nor the documentation are quite specific how to define a new highlight color. I see that I can use e.g. red but how to use an own color like a given RGB value? Sounds like the commands are quite different. But perhaps I miss something.

Comment: `\hl` -> `\highLight` and `\sethlcolor` -> `\LuaULSetHighLightColor` (and remove `\soulregister\LARGE7`). Tada! https://gist.github.com/moewew/af743d98e157a45a7331a1ad926b3787

Comment: Instead of using `\LuaULSetHighLightColor` you can also use `\highLight[{[#1]{#2}}]{#3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @moewe and @MarcelKrüger I found the following solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage{xcolor} % for highlighting AND background images-color!!!

\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color
\newcommand{\cText}[3][RGB]{%
    \begingroup
    \highLight[{[#1]{#2}}]{#3}%
    \endgroup
}
\definecolor{RGB2}{RGB}{35, 111, 161}
\definecolor{HTML3}{HTML}{bfedd2}

\begin{document}
Test z%
{\cText[HTML]{7e8c8d}
    {wecks U
       {\LARGE{}msetzung von größeren } % [2] <== not working
       {\color{HTML3}{}
           {\LARGE{}HTML}
           Text
       }-Entities \&<
    }
} 

Or simplified: z%
\highLight[{[RGB]{35, 111, 161}}]
    {wecks U
        {\LARGE{}msetzung von größeren } % [2] <== not working
        {\color{HTML3}{}
            {\LARGE{}HTML}
            Text
        }-Entities \&<
    }

Color check after ...

\end{document}
```

So my conclusion is that the `highLight` command already has this capability. Unfortunately this is **NOT** documented in the `lua-ul` Package description. Perhaps someone could update the docu!

Comment: Both `\LuaULSetHighLightColor` and the optional argument of `\highLight`/`\hl` are documented (explanation at the bottom of p. 1, example at the top of p. 2 in [the docs for `Lua-UL v0.0.4` \[2020/03/31\]](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/lua-ul/lua-ul.pdf)). What wasn't too clear to me was that it was possible to give the colour scheme as `\highLight[{[<scheme>]{<color spec.>}}]`. In any case if you want the documentation improved, it is much better to contact the author directly at https://github.com/zauguin/luaul/issues than to mention it in passing in a TeX.SX answer.