# Problem in writing inside the tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

    
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{calrsfs}

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\textheight=22.75truecm \textwidth=17cm \evensidemargin=-0.5cm
\oddsidemargin=-0.5cm \voffset-1.5cm

\pagestyle{headings}
\def\Spec{{\mathrm{Spec}\,}}
\def\Hom{{\mathrm{Hom}}}
\def\bHom{{\mathbf{Hom}}}
\def\bAut{{\mathbf{Aut}}}
\def\End{{\mathrm{End}}}
\def\Ext{{\mathrm{Ext}^1}}
\def\FEt{{\mathrm{FEt}}}
\def\Sets{{\mathrm{Sets}}}



\newenvironment{pf}
{\begin{proof}}
{ \end{proof}}

\newenvironment{function}
{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}}
{\end{tabular}
\end{center}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

 \begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5!white,colframe=white!50!black,  colbacktitle=white!75!black]
 \begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\underline{How can we test whether a given set of polynomials $G$ is a Gröbner basis or not?}}
  \end{flushleft}

   \end{tcolorbox}
   \end{document}
```

How do I fix this ? My writing is going outside the t-color box.

Comment: This seems to not be the fault of the `tcolorbox`, but of the underline. You can find an explanation for this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437779/) or in the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underline) for example.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it .

Comment: @smita Off-topic: do you know `tcolorbox` has options for flush left the text `halign=flush left`?

Comment: @CarLaTex No. I also want a breakable t-color box , something that is there continuing in 2 pages.How do i do that?

Comment: I  wanted to write paragraphs inside the t-color boxes? Will "halign=flush" left help me ?

Comment: @smita Zarko already answered for the breakable `tcolorbox`. For the paragraphs there is no problem, usually, please ask another question with an example of what you are not able to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of `\underline` try tu use `\ul` defined in the package `soul`.
- for breakable box you need to load `breakable` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % <---
\usepackage{soul}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5!white,colframe=white!50!black, 
                      colbacktitle=white!75!black,
                      fontupper=\bfseries, halign=left, breakable
                    ]
\ul{How can we test whether a given set of polynomials $G$ is a Gröbner basis or not?}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case that you prefer to use the `ulem` package, than in code you need to replace `\ul` with `\uline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{ulem}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5!white,colframe=white!50!black, 
                      colbacktitle=white!75!black,
                      fontupper=\bfseries,  halign=left, breakable
                    ]
\uline{How can we test whether a given set of polynomials $G$ is a Gröbner basis or not?}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before. The both MWE are compiled by XeLaTeX engine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I used the ulem package and it is working now

Comment: For breakable box, one also need to explicitly use the `breakable` option.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, you are right. Adding this library is not sufficient, you also need to ad it to box definition. I will correct answer ASAP.

Comment: @Zarko A standalone `\tcbset{breakable}` works as well, if user wants every box to be breakable.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, you are right again, however, I do not know, if OP like that all `tcolorboxes` are breakable. If yes, your suggestion is right way to go.