# How to force Latex print out reference items from Bibtex file?

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a thesis. I put all the references, including my own publications in a BIB file.

I want to create two sections like before:

\section {My Publications}

[1] my pub 1

[2] my pub 2

...

[9] my pub 9

\section {References} #other reference

[10] other pub 1

[11] other pub 2

...

The idea is to put all my references to the beginning of reference list. How could I do that in Latex?

Thank you very much

Comment: Use `biblatex`, we have some uestions on How to divide a reference list.

Comment: Or `multibib` if you want to use `bibtex`.

Comment: Did the other question solve your problem?

Comment: Oops, I think no. The problem is, usually my BibTex contains many pubs (let's say 100). I don't cite all of them, but just keep them here. Assume that I have 10 pubs, and 90 pubs belong to others. I cited 9 of my 10 pubs, and 70 of others. Now I want to force Latex to print all my 10 pubs (even 1 of them is not cited), but only 70 cited pubs of others.  The solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65114/biblatex-separating-publications-of-a-specific-author-in-the-bibliography will print all 100 pubs I think, which is not what I want.