# Biber: Filter bibliography with existing keywords by author name

Tags: biblatex, biber

A bibliography having entries from a specific author only should be created using biber's `sourcemap` feature. Answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/99345 shows how to do it with adding a certain keyword to each matching entry. This works for me as well, as long as **no keywords** were still present in matching bib entries. Thus, the following example produces a references list with only one entry instead of both entries.

[image: References list with only one entry]
[image: References list with both entries]

Removing the existing keyword `foo` in the second entry makes both entries appear in the list, as expected.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{first, author = {Doe, John}, title = {First}}
@book{second, author = {Doe, John}, title = {Second}, keywords = {foo}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author, match=Doe, final]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=doe, append]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=doe]
\end{document}
```

With `overwrite` and `append` attributes set, I assumed that also existing keywords can be modified that way. How can the intended behavior be achieved?

Comment: There are far fancier ways of filtering by name, I find (i.e. using hashes as alluded to in [Make specific author bold using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864) and spelled out in [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864)). But for your solution you should try and append `fieldvalue={,doe}` so that you are not left with `foodoe`, but `foo,doe` in a comma separated list.

Comment: Great, prepending a comma helped. I also added a `final` property in the question to fix the matching (makes no difference here, but with more bib entries not containing the author to filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keyword` field is a comma separated list. If you just append `doe` to a list like `keya,keyb` you get `keya,keybdoe`, but of course you want `keya,keyb,doe`, so you need to append `,doe` (that may leave you with an empty entry if the `keyword` field was empty, you might even get a warning, but you can ignore it). You would then use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author, match=Doe, final]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,doe}, append]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that instead of just appending a fixed string, you can use regexp match/replace. This could deal with the case where there is nothing to append to. Or write two maps with a regexp check first to see if there is anything in the target field.