# biblatex sourcemap for separating own publications does not work

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to provide a separate list of my own publications. For this purpose I have tried to use the solutions presented on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/112195). However, I can't get this to work. It seems that the matching doesn't work and no publication receives the required keyword. As I cannot find any debug messages for this, I am stuck.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=Wienke, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=ownpub]
    }
  }
}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{Wienke2012,
 author = {Wienke, Johannes and Klotz, David and Wrede, Sebastian},
 bookpagination = {page},
 booktitle = {Multimodal Corpora: How Should Multimodal Corpora Deal with the Situation?},
 date = {2012},
 editor = {Edlund, Jens and Heylen, Dirk and Paggio, Patrizia},
 eventdate = {2012-05-22},
 eventtitle = {LREC Workshop on Multimodal Corpora for Machine Learning: How should multimodal corpora deal with the situation?},
 keywords = {data set;middleware},
 pages = {46--49},
 title = {A Framework for the Acquisition of Multimodal Human-Robot Interaction Data Sets with a Whole-System Perspective},
 url = {http://michaelkipp.de/publication/MultimodalCorpora2012-proceedings.pdf},
 venue = {Istanbul, Turkey}
}
@techreport{Volpe2000,
 author = {Volpe, Richard and Nesnas, Issa A. D. and Estlin, Tara and Mutz, Darren and Petras, Richard and Das, Hari},
 date = {2000},
 institution = {Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology},
 location = {Pasadena, California},
 title = {{CLARAty}: Coupled Layer Architecture for Robotic Autonomy}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=ownpub,title={Own Publications}]{}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=ownpub]{}
\end{document}
```

My own publication (Wienke) should be in a separate list, but it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found out that this is caused by the fact that there are already keywords present for the publication and the default for maps is not to overwrite them. This can be changed:

```
\map[overwrite=true]{
  \step[fieldsource=author, match=Wienke]
  \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=ownpub]
}
```

Comment: There is also `append`. But then you need to supply a comma so that the last two keywords do not get merged. Then, however, you might get an empty keyword. So this needs a bit of fiddling to avoid all warnings.

Comment: @moewe thanks, I also fiddled with that and couldn't get it working. That explains why.

Comment: I normally just accept the warning about the empty keyword an always append a comma. That normally has no further consequence.