# Separate own publications and put them to beginning of reference list

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my thesis, and I would like to separate my own publications from the rest.

This means, I would like to assign some custom labels to them, and have them appearing at the beginning of the references list, one after the other (even though they are not the first papers in citatation order, and I do cite other papers between them in the text).

I am using biblatex, any ideas how can I achieve these?

EDIT :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}
\cite{own1}
\cite{ref2}
\cite{own2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Literature.bib:

```
@article{ref1,
title = {asdf1},
author = {asdf1}
}

@article{ref2,
title = {asdf2},
author = {asdf2}
}

@article{own1,
title = {asdf},
author = {ME}
}

@article{own2,
title = {asdf},
author = {ME}
}
```

In the output, under the reference section I'd like to have own1 and own2 at the beginning, like:

- [OWN1] ME, asdf
- [OWN2] ME, asdf
- [1] asdf1, asdf1
- [2] asdf2, asdf2

I am not sure what you mean by separate bibliography, I'm interested, might be acceptable as well.

Comment: Do they have to be at the beginning of the 'real bibliography'? Or would it be acceptable to have them in a separate bibliography? BTW: You can make your question easier to answer if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Some aspects of this question depend on the style and other specifics of your document.

Comment: You might also want to explain how your papers are going to be numbered and how the numbering for the other papers should look like. If you number by appearance, this might seriously mess things up.

Answer (score 3):

We can filter by name using PLK's solution to [biblatex: separating publications of a specific author in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864) and keywords. It is then really easy to create two separate bibliographies, one with the filtered work and one with all the rest. Using `labelprefix` and `refcontext` we can add the 'OWN' prefix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=phys, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
title = {asdf1},
author = {asdf1}
}

@article{ref2,
title = {asdf2},
author = {asdf2}
}

@article{own1,
title = {asdf},
author = {ME}
}

@article{own2,
title = {asdf},
author = {ME}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=ME,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=me]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}
\cite{own1}
\cite{ref2}
\cite{own2}

\printbibheading
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix={OWN}]
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=me]
\end{refcontext}%
\printbibliography[heading=none, notkeyword=me, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year! Thank you rescuing so many people from problems with bibliographies!

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much. Merry Christmas and a happy new year to you, too.