# \DeclareSourceMap does not work

Tags: biblatex, indexing, subdividing

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{custom.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=hit]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[keyword=hit]

\end{document}
```

Which as I understand it should add the keyword `hit` to all entries from an author named "Muster" which then can be printed with `\printbibliography[keyword=hit]` (as I have found it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65145/11820)

I compile the document with `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`, `xelatex` but I get the warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'hit' not found on input line 21.
```

and nothing is printed in the bibliography.

Are there any other specific pre-requirements for `\DeclareSourcemap` to work or am I understanding it completely wrong?

The `custom.bib` file is as follows:

```
@book{key,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des zweiten Bandes},
    volume = {2},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {muster, etwas}
}

@book{other,
    author = {Michael Karomann},
    maintitle = {Etwas},
    title = {Nichts},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {test, etwas}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. Non-empty fields are not overwritten unless `overwrite` is explicitly specified. (Empty fields are fine, though, this'll come in handy soon.)
2. You probably do not want to overwrite the existing keywords, instead you want to append `hit` to the keywords. If you do that, you also need to add a comma.

To catch both the cases with an undefined and non-empty keyword field, use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}]
    }
  }
}
```

The first `\map` only matches non-empty `keywords` field and adds `,hit` so hit does not meld into the last keyword as `keywords = {muster, etwashit}`. The second `\map` does not overwrite existing fields, so it only applies if no `keyword` field is defined. It simply makes the `keywords` field read `hit`.

MWE (This MWE uses `filecontents`. It therefore overwrites an existing `.bib` file with the same name as the `.tex` without advance warning. To be on the safe side test this in an empty folder.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des zweiten Bandes},
    volume = {2},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {muster, etwas},
}
@book{keya,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des Dritten Bandes},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
}
@book{other,
    author = {Michael Karomann},
    maintitle = {Etwas},
    title = {Nichts},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {test, etwas},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=hit]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naturally

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

would have been shorter, but that leaves an "empty keyword" in the `.bbl` if the `keywords` field was empty (`\keyw{,hit}`). This should not cause problems, but I consider this bad form.

If you are one of those people who are into the perverse habit of leaving fields empty as in `keywords = {}`, you need one further `\map`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, notmatch=\regexp{.+}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's a more elegant way to add a keyword to a list! (+1) I used to append comma, append keyword, remove comma in first position. Worked, but not pretty. By the way, would you care to expand on the use of `final` in the source maps' steps? Even though I do not consider myself "uninitiated", the documentation on Source Maps eludes me to a large extent. And this is one of the pieces I lack.

Comment: @gusbrs `final` stops execution of the entire "parent" `\map` (i.e. the `\map` the `\step` lives in) if the conditions for the current `\step` are not met. Otherwise the next step would be executed. Check out what happens in the MWE if `final` were not set in `\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}]`. In particular `final` aborts the `\step` if a `fieldsource` is not defined or if no `match` is found.

Comment: @gusbrs Mhhh, actually I quite like your idea of appending with a comma and then removing the leading comma. Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: If I get it correctly, if `final` was not present in `\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}]` the keyword would be added to all entries. Is this correct?

Comment: @gusbrs Exactly. Often you'll want `final` if you do sequential steps. But leaving away `final` allows you to put several unrelated `\step`s into the same `\map`.

Comment: I get it. I definitely need to take more care with that. Thank you!

Comment: @gusbrs I regularly forget the `final`. If the MWE does not include a test case where the mapping should not apply, it is quite easy to miss.

Answer (score 5):

This is a complement to [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420297/105447), just providing an alternative method to add a keyword without overwriting existing ones. It is done by appending `,keyword` to all entries of interest, irrespective of them being empty or not, and then removing and eventual leading comma, as the case may be.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A,}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des zweiten Bandes},
    volume = {2},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {muster, etwas},
}
@book{keya,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des Dritten Bandes},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
}
@book{other,
    author = {Michael Karomann},
    maintitle = {Etwas},
    title = {Nichts},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {test, etwas},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,hit}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A,}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=hit]
\end{document}
```

**Update**: Still another method. If keyword field is not empty, append a comma. Then append `keyword`. (I tried to fit it in a single map, but couldn't, perhaps there's a way).

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Or shorter (by moewe):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A(.+)\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1,}] %$
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @moewe, added yet another method.

Comment: AFAIK you can't get your second version into one map because you need the `final` in `\step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A.+\Z}, final]` you could try `\step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A(.+)\Z}, replace=\regexp{,$1}]` instead. I.e. only one `\map` with `\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Muster}, final]\step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A(.+)\Z}, replace=\regexp{,$1}]\step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={hit}, append]` haven't tested that, though.

Comment: @moewe, that does work! Incorporated it to the answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: I must add, I like this last one specially.