# biblatex filter on groups field

Tags: biblatex, biber

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333686/63717) explains how to create a filter that only has bibliography entries listed by `\printbibliography` for which *field==value* is true.

So, to check if an entry belongs to, let's say, Group1, I would define a filter similar to:

```
\defbibcheck{Group1}{ \iffieldequalstr{groups}{Group1}{}{\skipentry} }
```

but that obviously can't work because  I actually should be checking if Group1 is part of the list groups.

**How can that be accomplished?**

Here's a M(not)WE:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  groups = {Group1,Group2},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  groups = {Group1},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  groups = {Group2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\defbibcheck{Group1}{ \iffieldequalstr{groups}{Group1}{}{\skipentry} }
\printbibliography[check=Group1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the arbitrary field "group" there? If you are just trying to screen your bibliography, that could trivially achieved with keywords.

Comment: I think what he means @gusbrs is that group, as he wants to use it, is not a string field but a list. So he needs a check as to whether the list **contains** the group. In fact, however, I don't think "group" is a standard field anyway. Shouldn't he be using `keyword` to filter? I'm afraid I don't have time this morning to fiddle.

Comment: @PaulStanley Indeed, my first reading of the question misled me. But I understand it the same way as you do now. And my suggestion is, as yours, to use `keyword`s, except if there are unstated special requirements.

Comment: Note that the field `groups` has been introduced by JabRef to allow for explicit grouping of entries: https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/groups - The development team decided against a reuse of "keywords" as there was a strong opinion to keep "keywords" as specified by the author of the paper. Thus, they must not be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main reasons why this does not work out of the box as intended.

1. As mentioned by [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472207/biblatex-filter-on-groups-field#comment1190267_472207) the field `groups` is not a standard field and therefore not recognised by Biber. That means that the contents of the field `groups` don't make it to the `.bbl` file, which in turn means that `biblatex` can not access its contents.

   You would have to declare the `groups` field as shown in [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864)
2. Secondly, and more seriously, with `\iffieldequalstr{<field>}{<string>}` you only compare the (entire) contents of the field `<field>` to the string `<string>`. That means that `\iffieldequalstr{groups}{Group1}` yields false when groups is `groups = {Group1,Group2},`. This is also alluded to in Paul Stanley's comment.

Like [gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472207/biblatex-filter-on-groups-field#comment1190266_472207) and [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472207/biblatex-filter-on-groups-field#comment1190267_472207) I recommend you look into `keywords` as that field was intended to filter entries into groups.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author   = {Author, A.},
  year     = {2001},
  title    = {Alpha},
  keywords = {Group1,Group2},
}
@misc{B02,
  author   = {Buthor, B.},
  year     = {2002},
  title    = {Bravo},
  keywords = {Group1},
}
@misc{C03,
  author   = {Cuthor, C.},
  year     = {2003},
  title    = {Charlie},
  keywords = {Group2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=Group1]
\end{document}
```

If you have already populated hundreds of entries with `groups` instead of `keywords` you can use Biber to remap the fields.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=groups, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\A,}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

*edit* This now uses [gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105447/gusbrs)' method from [\DeclareSourceMap does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420332/35864) to avoid a leading comma without an item.

---

If for some reason you are wedded to the idea of a `groups` field and don't want to involve `keywords` at all, here is a crude implementation of a test that loops over a field with comma-separated values and checks if `Group1` is contained as list element in the `groups` field.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% make the groups field known to biblatex
\begin{filecontents*}{groups.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{groups}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{groups}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,datamodel=groups]{biblatex}

% traverse the groups field to find a match
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{bastianblx@isgroup}

\newcommand*{\bastianblx@ifmatch}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}
    {\toggletrue{bastianblx@isgroup}\listbreak}
    {}}

% switch the order of the arguments for easier \expandafter work
\newcommand*{\bastian@forcsvlist}[2]{%
  \forcsvlist{#2}{#1}}

\defbibcheck{Group1}{%
  \togglefalse{bastianblx@isgroup}%
  % 31 \expandafters for five levels of expansion
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter
  \bastian@forcsvlist
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter
  {\thefield{groups}}{\bastianblx@ifmatch{Group1}}%
  \iftoggle{bastianblx@isgroup}{}{\skipentry}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Alpha},
  groups = {Group1,Group2},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year   = {2002},
  title  = {Bravo},
  groups = {Group1},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year   = {2003},
  title  = {Charlie},
  groups = {Group2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[check=Group1]
\end{document}
```

All solutions show

[image: Bibliography with two items: <code>A01</code> and <code>B02</code>]

Comment: This is a brilliantly comprehensive answer. The `expandafter` ghastliness makes my head spin!

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a whole "menu"! (+1) You could, though, spread any of the nice techniques to get rid of that leading comma in the sourcemap: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420294/105447.

Comment: @gusbrs Done. The short version I went for (because it avoids code duplication) does not avoid a warning with `--trace`, though, so I opened https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/251.

Comment: @moewe Nice! I had not notice that warning, to be honest. I'll follow the thread there. Thanks.

Comment: @gusbrs I only saw it when I compiled with the `--trace` option, a normal `biber` call does not show it.

Comment: @moewe Oh, I see. I use that very last one method, I don't think that one leaves a leading comma in any circumstance, but I'll test it with `--trace` for the sake of it. I'm also curious on how the conditions to `condappend` might be stated.