# Biblatex: one document, multiple bibliographies built automatically from keywords. How to make references use the keyword as "label"?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I'm using Overleaf to write an article, and I have followed [the official tutorial for having multiple bibliographies in the same document](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document#Bibliographies_for_different_categories). This is working perfectly, just like on the official example below:

[image: Multiple Bibliograhies with biblatex - categories]

Considering that:

1. Each bibliography is taken from 1 .bib file (1:1 relationship);
2. Each bibliography is generated based on 1 keyword (1:1 relationship);
3. The keywords were added as the first keyword on each listed article on each .bib file, so each keyword exist only on 1 .bib file (1:1 relationship);
4. I'm 100% sure that no article had any of the manually inserted keywords before (no false positives, no duplicates).

I'd like to, somehow, make the citations use a specific style of "Keyword-A 1", "Keyword-B 1", etc.

Taking the official example and changing it a little, it would instead be rendered like that:

---

[Math 1] and [Physics 2] were published later than [Physics 1]. See also [Math 2].

**Math Readings**

- [Math 1] George A. Miller. “WordNet: a lexical database for English”. In: Communications of the ACM 38.11 (Nov. 1995), pp. 39–41. doi: 10.1145/219717.219748.
- [Math 2] M.A. Turk and A.P. Pentland. “Face recognition using eigenfaces”. In: Proceedings of 1991 IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition. IEEE Comput. Sco. Press, 1991, pp. 586–591. doi: 10.1109/CVPR.1991.139758.

**Physics Readings**

- [Physics 1] Kari Pulli et al. “Real-time computer vision with OpenCV”. In: Communications of the ACM 55.6 (June 2012), p. 61. doi: 10 . 1145 /2184319.2184337.
- [Physics 2] Steven B Giddings and Scott Thomas. “High energy colliders as black hole factories: The end of short distance physics”. In: Physical Review D 65.5 (2002), p. 056010.

---

**Question:** how can I do this, or at least something similar to this?

**Research made on StackExchange so far:**

1. [Biblatex: Distinguish citestyle of reference categories (my vs. others' publications)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581894/biblatex-distinguish-citestyle-of-reference-categories-my-vs-others-publicat): it indeed adds a custom "label" to the references based on a criteria, but the criteria "author name" is not the one I need;
2. [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299064/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings): it indeed makes the "labels" of references be different across bibliographies, but based only on defaulty-available styles ('alphabetic' and 'numerical') that have no relationship with the bibliography they are listed in;
3. [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings II](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415550/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings-ii): slightly different question, the author just wants to use the style 'numeric-comp' instead of 'numeric'. Again, these labels have no relationship with the bibliography they are listed in;
4. [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings II Part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457205/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings-ii-part-2): the solution to the previous question worked, but there was some sort of special characters encoding problem ("ä", "ö" being replaced by gibberish). I'm not having this problem and it is not related to having mutiple bibliographies in the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your question based on how it technically works:

1. What you are looking for in order to customize reference labels is called a `labelprefix`, because you want your references listed on `numerical` style, but with **prefixes** of your choice;
2. As you don't want to use the same prefix for all references, you'll need to set a `newrefcontext` between each bibliography, in order for each one to use its own prefix.

[This code by Ñako, from 3 years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557555/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings-ii-part-3), employs the aforementioned commands to achieve the desired result of the current question:

```
\printbibliography[env=bibliographyALPHA, title=Bibliography, keyword=primary]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=tech.\space]
\printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary, resetnumbers]
```

What they achieve is:

[image]

Here is [a "Ph.D. thesis template (physics)" template provided by Ivo Straka 2 years ago](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ph-dot-d-thesis-template-physics/tbpdfsmqcqkc) that achieves the same results with a slightly different code. It uses `\DeclareRefcontext` on the heading, then only the context name on `\newrefcontext`, instead of inline definition of labelprefixes on `\newrefcontext` .