# How to \printbibliography of one author, then of another author?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is it possible to `\print(the whole)bibliography` of one author and then further in the text to `\print(the whole)bibliography` of another author, and then a third author, etc. The entries that have at the same time the first and the second author should be printed once for each author. The authors might be cited at any rank in the author list. Different reference types (article, inproceedings, patent, etc.) are present in the bib file.

Here is a minimal example borrowed and adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346270/biblatex-biber-is-it-possible-to-printbibliography-between-two-years)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{a,
  date =     2001,
  author =   {Kennedy, J. and Clinton, B.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy and Kennedy, J. and Kennedy, J.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{c,
  date =     2005,
  author =   {Kennedy, J.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{d,
  date =     2007,
  author =   {Clinton, B.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{e,
  date =     2009,
  author =   {Biden, J.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{f,
  date =     2011,
  author =   {Clinton, B.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{g,
  date =     2013,
  author =   {Biden, J. and Clinton, B.},
  title =    {Title},
  booktitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@INPROCEEDINGS{h,
  date =     2001,
  author =   {Kennedy, J. and Clinton, B.},
  title =    {Inproc-Title},
  booktitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@INPROCEEDINGS{i,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy and Kennedy, J. and Kennedy, J.},
  title =    {Inproc-Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560247/35864

Comment: Did the linked Q&A help? Do you need help adapting the solution to your problem or is the answer there not what you were looking for?

Comment: The answer is there and my question appears as duplicate, sorry! However, another problem appeared to me ... it probably requires a new post, please let me know. When I tried combining at the same time printing bibliography of an author as suggested in the link you just posted and printing bibliography of that author between two years as you and @Guido suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346270/biblatex-biber-is-it-possible-to-printbibliography-between-two-years, I cannot use at the same time check=new and check= filternames \printbibliography[check=new, check=filternames].

Comment: OK, let's close this question here as a duplicate. I suggest you then ask a new question with new MWE about the remaining issue. I'm not sure at the moment (I'd have to check), but maybe you can only have one `filter` per `\printbibliography` call. If that is the case you can avoid the problem by combining the definition of the two filters `new` and `filternames` into one.