# How to implement two different Bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to have to two independent bibliographies. One "Bibliography" and a "Rechtssprechungsverzeichnis" on the next page with additional sources which I can insert into the text via \footcite{}.

I tried a few solutions but I did not get anywhere near what I want.
Thanks a lot.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend = biber,
    style = apa]{biblatex}
    
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \newpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \clearpage
    
    
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    {\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
    \input{sections/section1}
    
    \newpage
    
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
    }
    \printbibliography
    \nocite{WiWo}
    \end{document}
    
    @article{WiWo,
        Author = {Peter Steinkirchner and R{\"u}diger Kiani-Kress},
        Date-Added = {2019-06-05 12:52:11 +0200},
        Date-Modified = {2019-06-05 13:29:25 +0200},
        Journal = {WirtschaftsWoche},
        Number = {23},
        Pages = {15-22},
        Title = "{Die radikalen Kunden}",
        Year = {2019},
        }
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I need a second independent bibliography. In this case a "legal directory" in english. The bibliography shows the books, magazines etc. while the legal directory is supposed to show court decisions and so on.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28509/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65114.

Comment: Ah. Since you are using `biblatex`, this should not be too difficult. Depending on how you organize your `.bib` file(s), there are various options. Many are given in https://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/. It may help if you specify how the entries in the two bibliographies are meant to be distinguished (are you using distinct bib resources? can one item appear in both bibliographies? and other info like this.)

Comment: The entries would be totally separate. Like the one up above. This one would only appear in the "normal" bibliography file. The court orders on the other hand would only appear in the second bibliography file. They won't be mixed together.

Comment: You may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/119  then.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)