# 2 different bibliographies

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I'm writing my thesis and I would like to make 2 "bibliography" references:
The first one would be for the publications I'm in and the second one for external references.
I've made one *.bib file right now and it's working but I have no idea how I should work with 2 *.bib files.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: This can be done quite easily with [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). (There also is `multibib`) Would you mind using it? Is there any particular style (guide) you have to adhere to? I think a MWE would be of quite some help.

Comment: Solution with `biblatex`:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28509/biblatex-filter-out-publications-from-a-specific-author-in-the-references-dynam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chapterbib` package and use the `\bibliography` command as many times as you need it, each with your specified `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
And first bibliography.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{biblio1}

\section{Second section}
And second bibliography.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv} % (Optionnal) Re-specify the style of the bibliography
\bibliography{biblio2}

\end{document}
```

*biblio1* and *biblio2* being your `.bib` files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was something more difficult. I should've started doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the OP only needs to incorporate more than one `*.bib` file into the main `*.tex` file. With standard BibTeX, this is easy. Rather than the standard

```
\bibliography{bibfile1}
```

one can use a comma-separated list, as in

```
\bibliography{bibfile1,bibfile2}
```

Comment: I think the aim was to get two different bibliographies. This will just allow for two `.bib` files to appear in the same bibliography.