# Filter not found error using \printbiblist with biblatex (backend Biber)

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to generate a table of abbreviations from a subset of bibliography entries with short titles.  My idea is to use `\printbiblist{shorttitle}` with a filter so that only references with a certain keyword are included in the table of abbreviations.  Unfortunately, the filter isn't being recognized.  Here's a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{%
    \printfield{title}}

    \DeclareBiblistFilter{f1}{
    \filter[type=keyword,filter=Testkey]
    }
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{test1,
        AUTHOR = {John Doe},
        TITLE = {The Extraordinary Life of the Camel},
        SHORTHAND = {JIQ},
        SHORTTITLE = {ELC},
        JOURNALTITLE = {The Journal of Ideas Quarterly},
        VOLUME = {1},
        NUMBER = {1},
        YEAR = {1993},
        KEYWORD = {Testkey}
    }
    @ARTICLE{test2,
        AUTHOR = {James Clark},
        TITLE = {The Fantastic Life of the Giraffe},
        SHORTHAND = {JKQ},
        SHORTTITLE = {FLG},
        JOURNALTITLE = {The Journal of Knowledge Quarterly},
        VOLUME = {1},
        NUMBER = {1},
        YEAR = {1980},
        KEYWORD = {irrelevant}
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \begin{document}
    Title\autocite{test1} and then\autocite{test2}

    \printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations},filter=f1]{shorttitle}

    \end{document}
```

Here I'm trying to use the keyword "Testkey" to determine which items show up in the list of abbreviations, but I just get a "filter not found" error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your MWE.

First and foremost, in the `.bib` file, the field for keywords is called `keywords`, not `keyword`, note the **s**.

---

A BiblistFilter can only be used as the mandatory argument to `\printbiblist` and then needs a driver.
This is all predefined for `shorthand`, for other uses you will have to provide your own (as you did for `shorttitle`).

It cannot be used in the `filter` argument.

If you want to filter any bibliography list, you will need to declare a a bibfilter via `\defbibfilter` instead (this is valid for all of those `\print...` statements), see §3.6.10 Bibliography Filters and Checks, p. 82 for more details. You would probably go with

```
\defbibfilter{f1}{keyword=Testkey}
```

and then

```
\printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations},filter=f1]{shortitle}
```

---

But if you only want to check for keywords you can go with the `keyword` option to `\printbiblist` and just issue

```
\printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations},keyword=Testkey]{shortitle}
```

no need to declare any filters manually.

---

If you only want a list of entries with `shorttitle` & keyword "Testkey", then this BiblistFilter might help (you will need a driver)

```
\DeclareBiblistFilter{bf1}{
  \filter[type=field,filter=shorttitle]
  \filter[type=keyword,filter=Testkey]
}
```

---

Now the question is a philosophical one, whether you want to filter a list of entries with shorttitles, and would go with

```
\printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations},filter=f1]{shortitle}
```

or even

```
\printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations},keyword=Testkey]{shortitle}
```

Or if you want to display a list of entries with `shorttitle` and keyword "Testkey", in which case you need

```
\printbiblist[title={Table of Abbreviations}]{bf1}
```

with `bf1` as above and a suitable driver.

Comment: This was very helpful and solves my problem.  I was wondering if you could briefly explain what the bibliography drivers do and how to properly declare one (the one I used is just a copy from the biblatex documentation).  Also, ideally I'd like to filter by `author` rather than keyword.  I've thought of using `\addtocategory`, but then it seems I would need to enter all the keys manually.  Is there any way to automate this so as to produce a filter that includes only certain authors in the biblist?

Comment: @SAG Filtering by author names is a bit tricky, you can browse around here for some suggestions or ask a new question about that.

Comment: @SAG The bibliography driver specifies how an entry looks in the bibliography. Writing one is really a non-trivial matter and I don't feel that I could give a brief introduction that is sufficiently worked out.

Comment: I did figure out how to filer by author using `\addtocategory` by adapting code from the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28509/biblatex-filter-out-publications-from-a-specific-author-in-the-references-dynam/28555#28555).  I may post a question about bibliography drivers at some point.