# Add arguments to \declaresourcemap

Tags: biblatex, biber

Here is the MWE i used to list me references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, maxnames=6, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Knuth,
            final]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=knuth]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=Sigfridsson,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=sigfridsson]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,companion,worman,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography[keyword=knuth]
\printbibliography[keyword=sigfridsson]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=knuth,notkeyword=sigfridsson]
\end{document}
```

I am trying to create variables before the document starts so I can substitute any author needed in the document in my bib list. In a perfect world i would want it to look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, maxnames=6, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match= x,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue= x]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=x=anyauthorspecified]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=x=anyauthorspecified]
\end{document}
```

I want to do this so I can repeatedly use `\declaresourcemap` without having to make a map for each specific author when needed. I would just use a `\printbibliography` and specify which author i wanted

Comment: The problem is that you can only ever have one single `\DeclareSourcemap` in your document. If you have several, they overwrite each other. So this won't really work.

Comment: You could go for a different approach. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864, that should scale more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea from [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864) is scalable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\newcommand*{\generateauthorcategory}[3]{%
  \DeclareBibliographyCategory{by#1}%
  \DeclareIndexNameFormat{cat#1}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefstring{\namepartfamily}{#2}}
                and test {\ifdefstring{\namepartgiven}{#3}}}
      {\addtocategory{by#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
      {}}%
  \AtDataInput{\indexnames[cat#1][1-999]{author}}}

\generateauthorcategory{sigfridsson}{Sigfridsson}{Emma}
\generateauthorcategory{knuth}{Knuth}{Donald\bibnamedelima E.}
\generateauthorcategory{glashow}{Glashow}{Sheldon}

\defbibcheck{yr1986}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{1986}
       {}
       {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}

\defbibcheck{yr1984}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{1984}
       {}
       {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,sigfridsson,glashow,cicero,worman}
\printbibliography[category=bysigfridsson, title=Sigfridsson]
\printbibliography[category=byknuth, check=yr1984, title=Knuth 1984]
\printbibliography[category=byknuth, check=yr1986, title=Knuth 1986]
\printbibliography[category=byglashow, title=Glashow]
\end{document}
```

The command `\generateauthorcategory{<catname>}{<family>}{<given>}` generates a category `by<catname>` and adds all entries whose author has a family name equal to `<family>` and given name equal to `<given>`. Note that the given name needs to be given in the format from the `.bbl`, that means it might have to include some internal macros (`\bibnamedelima`, `\bibnamedelimd`, ...) (cf. Knuth above). The first argument `<catname>` must be unique and it should only contains ASCII chars (I prefer to keep it lowercase as well), it is only used internally and as identifier for `by<catname>`, so it need not bear any relation to the `<family>` or `<given>` argument - but of course it should to avoid confusion.

You can get all entries by an author by filtering the `by<catname>` category.

To filter by `year` you can add a simple bibcheck

```
\defbibcheck{yr1986}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{1986}
       {}
       {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}
```

add `check=yr1986` to `\printbibliography` to show only entries from 1986. With `\ifnumgreater` and `\ifnumless` you can also check for year ranges.

Comment: It works great! If i wanted to also specify by the year would i just need to make another \declarebibliographycatergory for the year category?

Comment: @Michael Depends on what exactly you want. Can you elaborate? Do you want to filter by author and year? How do you filter by year (younger than, older than, between x and y)?

Comment: How would I filter if I wanted to present a list of authors' publications from only 2017 (between x and y might work also if I can still just specify one year if needed)?

Comment: @Michael See the edit, please.

Comment: It will only cite the "@inproceedings" and doesn't include the "@article" bibs. How can I have it cite both?

Comment: @Michael There is nothing in the code that would prevent it from working with `@article`. So if it doesn't work for you, please ask a new question with an MWE.