# List references by authors with same last name

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to list the references of two different people with the same last name:

```
\newcommand*{\generateauthorcategory}[3]{%
 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{by#1}%
 \DeclareIndexNameFormat{cat#1}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefstring{\namepartfamily}{#2}}
                and test {\ifdefstring{\namepartgiven}{#3}}}
      {\addtocategory{by#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
      {}}%
  \AtDataInput{\indexnames[cat#1][1-999]{author}}}


\generateauthorcategory{foo}{Foo}{Andrew}
\generateauthorcategory{foo}{Foo}{Fernand}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2018,]
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2017,]
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2016,]

\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2018,]
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2017,]
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoo, check=yr2016,]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

It tells me I already have a foo catergory so i cant have two.

Comment: `\generateauthorcategory{fooa}{Foo}{Andrew}
\generateauthorcategory{foof}{Foo}{Fernand}` and then `category=byfooa` and `category=byfoof` respectively? The first argument of `\generateauthorcategory` must be unique and should only contain ASCII chars (I prefer to keep them lowercase) - it is however only used internally and so need not bear relation to the second and third arguments.

Comment: I assume the code is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397832/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406061/35864. In the future it would be great if you could give a link to the solution. And please also consider posting a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just code snippets. A full code example that we can run directly makes it much easier to help you: We can get started more quickly and we can be sure that we are actually talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument `<catname>` of `\generateauthorcategory` as defined in [Add arguments to \declaresourcemap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397832/35864) is an 'internal' name that is used to identify the bibliography category `by<catname>`. That name must be unique across all `\generateauthorcategory`s so there are no clashes between categories for different people (in your example which *Foo* do you expect to see with `category=byfoo` *Andrew* or *Fernand*?). Since `<catname>` is used for internal purposes it should only contain ASCII chars and I prefer to keep the characters lowercase as well. The `<catname>` identifier need not bear a relation to the other two arguments, but of course it helps if it does.

You will need to choose two different names here, for example `fooa` and `foof`,

```
\generateauthorcategory{fooa}{Foo}{Andrew}
\generateauthorcategory{foof}{Foo}{Fernand}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfooa]
\printbibliography[heading=none, category=byfoof]
```